# How do I get typer to accept the short `-h` as well as the long `--help` to output help text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, typer

Out of the box, [Typer CLIs](https://typer.tiangolo.com/typer-cli/) only recognize the long help option `--help` to display the help text.

I would like to also accept the short option `-h` but I can't figure out how. I've searched the docs to no avail.

Do I need to alias `-h` to `--help` and if so, how do I do that?

Comment: `app = typer.Typer(context_settings={"help_option_names": ["-h", "--help"]})`

Comment: Thanks @jvx8ss! I'd be happy to accept this answer if you turn it into one.
How do I add the context settings to `typer.run(entry_point)`?

Comment: Sadly you cant pass `context_settings` to `typer.run` as of now

Comment: Thanks! I see, so I need to turn the app into one using decorators. But then: how do I avoid having to use subcommands? See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74404332/how-to-make-a-typer-app-using-decorators-without-having-to-use-subcommands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is to use `context_settings={"help_option_names": ["-h", "--help"]})`

As suggested by @jvx8ss in the comments, one needs to convert a `typer.run` app to one using `@app.command()` decorators.

Here is a minimal working example:

```py
import typer

app = typer.Typer(context_settings={"help_option_names": ["-h", "--help"]})


@app.command()
def main(name: str):
    print(f"Hello {name}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()
```