# How to make a Typer app using decorators without having to use subcommands?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, typer

I have a simple Typer app that uses the minimal `typer.run(main)` way of setting up.

I would like to add `context_settings` to this app - to that end, I think I need to convert the invocation to one that uses decorators `@app.command()`.

But in contrast to the Typer documentation, I *do no* want to use any subcommands, I want my app to stay simple. How do I do this?

In the documentation, it seems that when you use `@app.command()` you will have to use a subcommand going by the name of the function that's decorated with `@app.command()`, see: https://typer.tiangolo.com/tutorial/commands/#a-cli-application-with-multiple-commands

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if you use only one single `@app.command()` decorator Typer automatically obviates the need for a subcommand. Only when you use 2 or more `@app.command()`s do you need to call each command using the function name.

The following minimal script can still be invoked using `python main.py Jane`, no need for `python main.py main Jane`:

```py
# Filename: main.py

import typer

app = typer.Typer()


@app.command()
def main(name: str):
    print(f"Hello {name}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()
```

Comment: You can also pass `context_settings` decorating it with `@app.command(context_settings={"help_option_names": ["-h", "--help"]})`

Comment: @jvx8ss I think that comment is for the other question :)